# Using log4j with JBoss 7.1

Tags: log4j, jboss7.x

How can I use log4j with JBoss 7.1?

I have a log4j-1.2.16.jar in my WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder. When I output the result of `Logger.getRootLogger().getClass().toString()` I get `class org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger` which is wrong.

If I add `Dependencies: org.apache.commons.logging` to my *MANIFEST.MF* file I get the same result.

This results into the problem that my *log4j.properties* file (which I created unter WEB-INF/classes) is ignored.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There will soon be a way that [will just work for you](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-514), but currently you have to exclude the log4j dependency from your deployment. You will also have to manually invoke the PropertyConfigurator.configure() to load the properties file.

The following file ([jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile)) needs to contain the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then adding including your own version of log4j in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory should work as you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was really frustrated.

Comment: What doesn't work? What version of JBoss AS or WildFly?