# log4j configuration with jboss7 issue

Tags: java, spring, log4j, jboss7.x

java code

```
 public static synchronized void init(String log4jXMLPath) //throws ServletException
   {
      try
      {
         if (!initialized) // set the global RepositorySelector
         {
            defaultRepository = LogManager.getLoggerRepository();
            RepositorySelector theSelector = new AppRepositorySelector();
            **LogManager.setRepositorySelector(theSelector, guard);**
            initialized = true;
         }
         Hierarchy hierarchy = new Hierarchy(new RootLogger(Level.DEBUG));
         //loadLog4JConfig(servletContext, hierarchy);
         loadLog4JConfig(hierarchy, log4jXMLPath);
         ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
         repositories.put(loader, hierarchy);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {

         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

**LogManager.setRepositorySelector(theSelector, guard);** this line in java code throwing an error

stacktrace

```
18:17:11,189 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to reset the LoggerFactory without possessing the guard.
18:17:11,190 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.setRepositorySelector(LogManager.java:164)
18:17:11,191 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at com.mportal.logger.api.AppRepositorySelector.init(AppRepositorySelector.java:73)
18:17:11,192 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at com.mportal.logger.api.MPLoggerImpl.loadLogInstance(MPLoggerImpl.java:64)
18:17:11,192 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at com.mportal.logger.api.MPLoggerImpl.<init>(MPLoggerImpl.java:38)
18:17:11,192 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
18:17:11,193 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
18:17:11,194 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
18:17:11,194 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
```

How to solve this one? Please give solutions.

Comment: 1) Format your code correctly 2) Explain what context this error is occuring 3)Just dumping stack-trace without explanation will not be able for anyone to help you

Comment: See this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584787/using-log4j-with-jboss-7-1 You might have to exclude log4j dependency from JBoss

Answer (score 1):

```
LogManager.setRepositorySelector(theSelector, guard);
```

You can only use one guard, using different guard objects will result in the observerd error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to reset the LoggerFactory without possessing the guard.
```

It should be possible to pass `null` as a parameter to the function. Or simply hold a reference to the initial set guard.

The documentation states:

*Initally the guard is null. If the guard is null, then invoking this method sets the logger factory and the guard. Following invocations will throw a IllegalArgumentException, unless the previously set guard is passed as the second parameter.*