# Getting Log4J to work with JBoss Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, log4j

I'm using JBoss EAP6 (AS7) standalone.

To get Log4j.xml in myproject/WEB-INF/classes to work:

1. I add a log4j exclusion to jboss-deployment-structure.xml (as mentioned in the answer to [Using log4j with JBoss 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584787/using-log4j-with-jboss-7-1))
2. add "" to system-properties in jboss' standalone.xml.

It works fine and is able to log all the classes that are in my application correctly (ie. au.com.example.controllerA), however for hibernate the logging is still using the settings defined in standalone.xml subsystem "urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2".

My log4j.xml

```
... 
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
...
```

My jboss standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2">
...
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
...
</subsystem>
```

If I add the following into my standalone.xml logging subsystem, hibernate sql will show:

```
    <logger category="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
```

I suspect it's because the application is using the jboss managed hibernate. Can anyone verify this?

If so, I want to run different applications on my jboss that logs the hibernate logs into different files based on the application. Is there a way to do this with a jboss managed hibernate?

Comment: I've not done this myself so sorry I can't give an answer but perhaps http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/logsep.html would help?